# Would a container made of sugar eventually dissolve if filled with a sugar-saturated solution of water?

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solutions, precipitation

Suppose you had a bottle made of sugar glass, and filled it with water that was already saturated with sugar.

I know that with a fully saturated solution of sugar in water, no additional sugar can dissolve in the water. However, just like how a reaction in an equilibrium state simply has equal amounts of transformations between the two substances in both directions, could sugar from the water randomly precipitate and sugar from the walls of the container at those points in time dissolve into the liquid? If this process continued for long enough, the water could, hypothetically, dissolve its container and break free. My question is simply whether this could happen.

When thinking about this as a form of equilibrium, I’m reminded of the triple point of a substance—that, too, is an equilibrium, but even in equilibrium, the substance shifts between all of the states. I know these are not directly related in the sense in which I’m talking about, but it highlights what is possible for an equilibrium.

I would assume that whatever principle governs the answer to this question also applies to any substance dissolved to full saturation in any liquid, which is made into a container into which that liquid is placed.

Comment: Is is similar case as for halogen incandescent bulbs. If tungsten vapours  were returned to the places from which they evaporated, it could shine eternally. But they are returned elsewhere and they eventually get the filament broken. It could take very long time for the sugar case.

Comment: Remember also recrystalization of near unsoluble precipitates in gravimetry, like BaSO4. It has initially very small particles, partially passing paper filters. the procedure includes heating the suspension, accelerating dissolving smaller ones and growth bigger ones, what is thermodynamically preferred. Not exactly the same case, as there are very very tiny differences in solubility, but almost there.

Comment: Arguably, with sugar it won't take as long as with tungsten.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I would rather agree. But hard to make  time estimation and hard to test. They seldom sell  bottles from sugar glass these days. "Very long" was meant absolutely, not relatively wrt a halogen bulb.

Comment: You picked a bad example, I think. In lieu of such speculation, you better read about supersaturation.

Comment: Consider that you can buy sugar-syrup sweets with a hard sugar shell (try saying that five times fast!). See this patent for how they're made, https://patents.google.com/patent/US4614658A/en, or this example product: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Arcor-Assorted-Filled-Fruit-BonBons-Bulk-Hard-Candy-assorted-fruit-candies-4-pounds/756758946 . My guess is shelf life is decades, if not centuries.

Comment: The sugar will be slowly dissolving and recrystallizing That does not mean the crystallization takes place where the dissolving did. It takes time A similar process happens in limestone caverns or in the old way of making apple jack by freezing a barrel of hard cider [in places like Minnesota and the Adirondack area of New York].